# Is local storage the best way to store JWT token on client side? ( Assuming best practices are in place for preventing XSS )

Tags: api, jwt, token

Let us say you are taking the needed steps to prevent XSS such as input validation, and input Sanitizing, also you are very careful about XSS so you do daily code reviews that checks for malicious code;
Would storing a JWT token in browser local storage is the safest in this situation compared to storing it in a cookie or http only cookie ?

To describe this more lets say the JWT access token lives in a redux store in a REACT APP. The app auto-log out users after 1 hour of inactivity. You provide the token as a global state.

The access token for authenticated users only keeps them in the authorized part of the site, they can not use it to retrieve anything from the backend.

Note: Nothing on your application is safe when you are not preventing XSS by daily code reviews.

Comment: For effective XSS prevention, consider `CSP` Content Security Policy along with code reviews.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether storing JWT in local storage makes them more or less safe, the general answer is that it doesn't matter, as JWT are tamper proof, and any attempt to modify them will immediately be detected by the server which issued them.  In terms of protecting any visible data contained in a JWT, storing them in local storage increases the chances that prying eyes might see this data.  If this be a concern, then consider encrypting them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is what I thought really.  if you do not mind, another question.. what is the point of encrypting the token, there are multiple free hash analyzers out there. People can even code their owns. lets  say I used MD5 or MD4 to encrypt the keys. Someone intelligent enough to know how to hack will know how to decrypt such keys ?

Comment: Your question above sort of answers the question in your comment.  Just because JWTs cannot be tampered with does not mean that their contents cannot be seen on the client.  If you don't want to risk someone hacking your local storage and seeing things like usernames etc. then encrypting the JWT is one option.

Comment: JWT are identifiers. Using XSS the JWT can be stolen and the hacker can impersonate the user without knowing the credentials. So, JWT not being tamper proof may not solve the JWT hijacking problem.

Comment: @Ramesh Good point.  Many security minded sites, such as banking sites, will give their JWT a very short lifespan, to deal with the problem you mentioned.

Comment: The Http Only cookie was brought to avoid the Cookie hijacking via injected javascript. Modern technique is `CSP`. It will allow us to instruct what scripts are allowed to execute. Blocking eval and inline will help reduce the risk of XSS

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Agreed. It may not solve the attack vector completely. Also, if the refresh token is available and leaked the attacker can get a new session token.